# Invoking cts through batch

Tags: cts

I would like to run cts on windows using batch script. I want to run Android CTS 5.0 R3 version on windows 64 bit.

My script has the below command to invoke cts:

java -cp ddmlib-prebuilt.jar;tradefed-prebuilt.jar;hosttestlib.jar;cts-tradefed.jar -DCTS_ROOT=D:\cts com.android.cts.tradefed.command.CtsConsole

When I double click on my batch script,  it will enter into a shell like "cts-tf>". I then have to manually run cts using " run cts --plan CTS " command.

I would like to put "run cts --plan CTS" command also as well as part of my batch script. i.e. when command prompt has entered into shell, I need to execute run cts --plan CTS from my batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp ddmlib-prebuilt.jar;tradefed-prebuilt.jar;hosttestlib.jar;cts-tradefed.jar -DCTS_ROOT=android-cts-6.0_r13-linux_x86-arm com.android.cts.tradefed.command.CtsConsole
```

Comment: Please provide a description for why your code works in addition to posting code.